# How do I call a function in an external js file using typescrpt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webpack

We are trying a POC of adding Typescript and Webpack to our Angularjs project.
I am able to get my webpack bundle to generate, however at runtime the program cannot find the various functions in my validator.js.  Can you please offer some advice?

*login-view.components.ts*

```
declare var findFormNode: any;      //function in validator.js


 //LogInUser
 self.login = function ($event, command) {
     if (findFormNode($event.target.id)) {
     ...
     }
}
```

*main.ts*  is importing the file

```
import "./../../../CommonStaticFiles/include/js/Validators.js";
```

*bundle.js*

```
eval("/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function($) {/*\r\n\r\n  VALIDATORS\r\n\r\n ... n\n\nfunction findFormNode(
```

---

### error

```
ReferenceError: findFormNode is not defined
at LoginController.self.login (login-view.component.ts:28)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:NaN), <anonymous>:4:267)
at callback (angular.js:29019)
```

Comment: How are you exporting your functions inside of `Validators.js`?

Comment: Currently I'm not exporting anything in the validator.js

Comment: That is likely a part of the problem. Please see my answer below and let me know if it's of any help

Comment: If i want to import all can i export all as well?

Comment: You can export all of the functions at the bottom of the `Validators.js` file like so: `export {func1, func2, func3}` etc. For reference, here's the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) on using `export`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your functions to be properly imported, there are few things that you have to make sure of.

First, make sure you are exporting your functions correctly. Here's an example of how to export a function from `Validator.js`:

```
export const validateFunc1 = ():void => {};
```

Next, you have to make sure you are using proper import syntax. In order to import the function above, you would do the following:

```
import {validateFunc1} from "./../../../CommonStaticFiles/include/js/Validators.js";
```

Alternatively, if you want to import all exported functions at once, then you can use this syntax:

```
import * as validatorFuncs from "./../../../CommonStaticFiles/include/js/Validators.js";
```

Lastly, check that the location of `Validators.js` is correct. It's a common mistake to be looking in the wrong directory. Your code editor can usually help you find the right path to use.

Comment: Nice, so i imported all the functions  (and added the exports) and added a prefix to my function call.  "validatorFuncs.findFormNode".  Works like a charm.

Comment: Great, glad to help. Best regards